# Create XML using an Existing Model

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create an `XML` string.. I want to insert this `xml` string to my database field named `DocumentData` datatype of this field is `xml`... I'm using this field as a backup....

here's my code:

```
    public string XMLDoc(SalesForecastModel model)
    {
        string doc = string.Empty;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            writer.WriteStartElement("root");

            writer.WriteStartElement("SalesForecast");

            writer.WriteStartElement("Node2");
            writer.WriteString("inner text");
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("EntryNumber");
            writer.WriteString(model.EntryNumber);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

but it gives me this result:
when I tried to put the value of the model it the `entrynumber` doesn't have a complete format... but when I do a fixed call like node2 it works fine... thanks in advance

```
<root>
  <SalesForecast>
    <Node2>inner text</Node2>
    <EntryNumber />
  </SalesForecast>
</root>
```

Comment: Are you sure that EntryNumber property is populated? Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: yeah my bad.. I wasn't able to populate it... it works now...